# .show() not working on button id from array

Tags: jquery, arrays, show, show-hide

There are a group of buttons I'm wanting to show based on the class that is associated with the button.

What I am doing is grabbing the id's of buttons with a specific class and placing them in corresponding arrays.  I am then hiding all buttons regardless of class and then based on a button click, a specific array is selected and the buttons associated with the id's within the array are shown.

My problem is that when I try the below code, the show does not work.

```
$.each(cadetInfoIds, function(i, val){
    $('#categoryButtonGroup #' + i).show();
});
```

..but, when I do this, it works

```
$.each(cadetInfoIds, function(i, val){
    $('#categoryButtonGroup #show_info1').show();
});
```

Here is the associated code:

```
<div class="col-md-4"  id="categoryButtonGroup">
    <button type="button" class="btn cInfo mInfo dInfo fInfo" id="show_info1">Info 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn cInfo mInfo dInfo" id="show_info2">Info 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn mInfo dInfo fInfo" id="show_info3">Info 3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn dInfo fInfo" id="show_info3">Info 3</button>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() { 
    var cInfoIds = [];
    $("#categoryButtonGroup").find(".cInfo").each(function(){ cInfoIds.push(this.id); });

    InitializePage();

    function InitializePage(){
        ShowItemsByCategory('c');
        SetButtons();
    }
    function ShowItemsByCategory(category){
        $('#categoryButtonGroup button').hide();

        switch (category) {
        case 'c':
            $.each(cInfoIds, function(i, val){
                $('#categoryButtonGroup #' + i).show();
                //$('#categoryButtonGroup #show_info1').show();
            });
            break;
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `$("#categoryButtonGroup .cInfo").show()` instead of saving all the IDs in an array?

Comment: Thank you Barmar, that makes much more sense and makes it much more efficient.  if you use that as an answer I'll mark it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving all the IDs in an array, you can just use the class when you want to show everything.

```
$("#categoryButtonGroup .cInfo").show();
```

I have a feeling you may even be able to get rid of the `switch` statement. It looks like the first letter of all the `*Info` classes is the category code, so you can do:

```
$("#categoryButtonGroup ." + category + "Info").show();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `val` not `i` since this last one is a numeric index. Parameter `val` contains the array element.

```
$.each(cadetInfoIds, function(i, val){
    $('#categoryButtonGroup #' + val).show();
});
```

Since and `id` identifies an unique element on your page, you don't need to use a selector hierarchy. You can get rif of `#categoryButtonGroup`

```
$.each(cadetInfoIds, function(i, val){
    $('#' + val).show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't sure what the issue was and added the #categoryButtonGroup to see if it was a visibility issue.